# Convert jQuery object of 'multiple elements without parent' to string

Tags: jquery, string, tinymce

I wanted to manipulate HTML by selecting elements and convert entire object to string so I can `setContent()` in tinyMCE.

Problem is if there is no parent element then while converting tostring only first element is converted while rest of elements are stripped. A simple example,

```
var elem = jQuery('<p class="first"></p><p class="second"></p>');
elem.prop('outerHTML');
```

will show output as

```
"<p class="first"></p>"
```

and strip rest of the elements. How can I convert jQuery object to string without losing elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map them, and then join them.

```js
var test = $('<p class="first"></p><p class="second"></p>').map(function(){ return this.outerHTML; }).get().join('');
console.log(test);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var elem = jQuery('<p class="first"></p><p class="second"></p>');
var str=""
elem.each(function(index,item){
str+=item.outerHTML
})
console.log(str)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var elem = jQuery('<p class="first"></p><p class="second"></p>');
var strHtml='';
$.each(elem,function(index,value){
   strHtml+=value.outerHTML;
   console.log(value);
});
console.log(strHtml);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```